# Android how to parser a Json Error Object

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I want to parse my json Errors Object

this is the json :

```
{"errors":["The name must be at least 4 characters.","The username must be at least 3 characters.","The password must be at least 6 characters."]}
```

here is the code :

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);

if (jObject.has("errors")){
// PARSE RESULT 
String errors = jObject.getString("errors");

Utils.makeAlertDialog(getActivity(), "Ops!", errors, false);
```

The Problem is that this is how the string is displaying :

```
["The name must be at least 4 characters.","The username must be at least 3 characters.","The password must be at least 6 characters."]
```

I want to remove the [] and the "". Can someone advice pls. thanks

to be like:

```
-The name must be at least 4 characters.
-The username must be at least 3 characters. 
-The password must be at least 6 characters.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In post JSON string `errors` is `JSONArray` instead of String so you should first get `errors` from `JSONObject` then iterate over Array to get Strings:

```
JSONArray arrArrors = jObject.getJSONArray("errors");
//iterate to arrArrors get all values
for(int i=0;i<arrArrors.length;i++) {
  String error = arrArrors.optString(i);
  Log.i("JSONDATA","error :: "+error);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

errors is a `JSONArray`:

```
JSONArray errors = jObject.optJSONArray("errors");
for (int i = 0; i < errors.length(); i++) {
    String errorAtIndex = errors.optString(i);
}
```

From the documentation: `optString(index)`

> Returns the value at index if it exists, coercing it if necessary.